# @google-cloud/logging-winston not logging from NodeJS after some time inside a GCE instance

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, winston, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

Node: 10.16.0

@google-cloud/logging-winston: 2.0.0

Server: GCE VM Instance

I'm logging to stackdriver from my node process running an a GCE instance. I'm adding the following object to my winston transports

```
new require("@google-cloud/logging-winston").LoggingWinston({
  projectId: "my-google-project-id"
})
```

After deployment to GCP and starting the node process, I'm getting the logs in GCP Logs Viewer. So far so good. After a couple of hours(or in some cases minutes), I stop getting any logs in the Log Viewer. When I check the node process on my VM Instance, it is still running and writing logs to the console. But the google-cloud transport does not work at all. If I stop the node process and start a new one again, I start getting logs on the Logs Viewer again. But again it stops logging after some time. I tried downgrading from @google-cloud/logging-winston@2.0.0 to 1.1.1, but still the same. Could it be that I'm hitting some quotas? Or could it be because there is some uncaught error and @google-cloud/logging-winston fails from thereon?

Answer (score 0):

In some instances it's possible that the some logs are skipped due to permission related issues. Make sure that your service account has the appropriate permissions [1].

Here is our documentation on how to set up Winston, just in case it had not crossed your eyes [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/troubleshooting#verify-creds

[2] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs#using_winston

Comment: The logrotate issue mentioned in the first link could be my problem. I'm running node app using `pm2` and I have pm2 logrotate setup. Is there anything particular that I have to do so that the stackdriver logging does not break due to it??

Comment: The documentation recommends a workaround of using nocopytrucate setting and mentions that in order to prevent it from breaking you will need to restart the agent periodically.

Comment: I don't think logrotate is the issue. I'm not using the agent. I'm using the node js library for logging. The logrotate issue is mentioned for the logging agent which I'm not using.